# Why is a comment added automatically when flagging a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, comments

When flagging a question as a duplicate, a comment is posted automatically. This is really bad because the user who has asked the question knows I have flagged their question. I don't like it.

Why doesn't Stack Overflow at least ask for confirmation before posting an automatic comment?

Comment: You can also always delete your comment, if you feel strongly about it. If you're quick, they likely won't get a notification about it, either.

Comment: Flagging for closure as a duplicate shouldn't be seen as a negative thing. You're helping someone find the answer to their question, which is presumably what they wanted.

Answer (score 10):

The whole point of flagging something as a duplicate is to help the OP find their answer. The comment helps them find that answer even faster.

And once a post is closed, your name is *also going to be on the close banner*, if you are not comfortable with that link then your only option is to refrain from flagging posts for closure (duplicate or otherwise).

Comment: I think it should be mentioned on SO Terms and conditions or privacy policy page that sometimes OS will make automatic comments.

Comment: @Admin: that'd be a separate feature request you could make. However, I fail to see what that would achieve. Should it list all actions that might result in content being visible somewhere else than where you took that action? Interaction with this site *implies you are consenting with your profile being visible in various places*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nevertheless, the assumption that flagging is a private channel between the flagger and the site's moderators isn't wrong. Although I don't agree there's anything wrong with the automated duplicate comment, I can completely understand being surprised by it.

Comment: Agree with Yannis. Unlike closevoting, flagging comes with the expectation of anonymity. The automated comment is breaking that expectation.

Comment: @yannis: yes, the distinctions between community-handled and moderator-handled flags are hard to spot sometimes.